# Sending data with radio buttons

Tags: php, template-lite

I need to send some data with radio button.

This buttons are

```
<td>
  <span style="color:red">Sil</span>
    <input name="{$spam.encId}-{$spam.comment}-{$spam.to}-{$spam.userId}" type="radio" value="DENIED"><br>
  <span style="color:green">Onayla</span>
    <input name="{$spam.encId}-{$spam.comment}-{$spam.to}-{$spam.userId}" type="radio" value="ACCEPTED">
</td>
```

This buttons exist like that

In php side, i print all data which radio keeps. The problem is that only first button works correctly. I cannot put data second and third one.

[image]

This is the code.What might be the reason ?

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div class="destek_inside" >
    <table width="1000" border="1" class="std">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="header">
          <td class="pd_5 bold per25">Kullanıcı Adı</td>
          <td class="pd_5 bold per25">İçerik</td>
          <td class="pd_5 bold per25">Yorum</td>
          <td class="pd_5 bold per25">Durum</td>
        </tr>
        {foreach from=$spams value=spam}
          <tr>
            <td class="pd_5">
              <a href="{$spam.userUrl}" class="no_link_style bordo" target="_blank">{$spam.user.username}({$spam.userId})</a>
            </td>
            <td class="pd_5">
              <a href ="{$spam.typeUrl}" target="_blank">{$spam.typeData.name} {$spam.typeData.surname}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="pd_5">{$spam.comment}</td>
            <td>
              <span style="color:red">Sil</span>
                <input name="{$spam.encId}-{$spam.comment}-{$spam.to}-{$spam.userId}" type="radio" value="DENIED"><br>
              <span style="color:green">Onayla</span>
                <input name="{$spam.encId}-{$spam.comment}-{$spam.to}-{$spam.userId}" type="radio" value="ACCEPTED">
            </td>
          </tr>
        {/foreach}
      </tbody >
    </table>
  </div>
  <p align="right"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Kaydet"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: no it must be different. The actual problem is that I cannot take second and third one in php side

Comment: Every radio button in a group of radio buttons all must have the same name but different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you place $spam.comment to the radio button's name. The second entry has quotes in the text. So you have invalid name:

«input name="......"c"...."

This is the reason, that you have data from the first radio only

Comment: probably you can pass just the message's ID. And store other data in DB or session.

If you haven't unique ID for your messages, you could use MD5 hash for instance